# React useState gives old value with in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have declared a state and updating it based on condition; however, When I am trying to access the value it gives me the old state value. Could any please guide me how to implement the issue?

```js
const [isScrollReached, setIsScrollReached] = useState(false);
  const onScrollIntentTriggerFn = event => {
    if (window.pageYOffset / document.body.offsetHeight > 0.6) {
      console.log("11")
      setIsScrollReached(true);
    }
    if (window.pageYOffset / document.body.offsetHeight < 0.05 && isScrollReached ) {
      console.log('User scroll to 60% and came back to top of the screen');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScrollIntentTriggerFn);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScrollIntentTriggerFn);
    };
  }, []);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[Please find the sample code and Looking for the possible solution](https://playcode.io/1491626)

Comment: where are you accessing it?

Comment: The initial value of `isScrollReached` is part of the closure for your callback that is registered with `window scroll`. If you need to access the live value you can use a `ref` with `const scrollRef = useRef();` and access it via `scrollRef.current`

Answer (score 1):

The event listener you set up inside the `useEffect` will not take into account the new values of the `isScrollReached` state, because it only uses the value of the state the moment was added using `window.addEventListener`.

considered the following, relatively simple, example:

```ts
const [count, setCount] = useState(5)

  function onWindowClick(e: MouseEvent) {
    console.log(`count in event listener (won't change!): ${count}`)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('click', onWindowClick)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('click', onWindowClick)
    }

  }, [])

  return (
    <main>
      <p>value of count after rerender: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prev => prev + 1)}>Add to count</button>
    </main>
  )
```

The initial value of the `count` state is `5`. When the `useEffect` runs, it takes that value and uses it inside the event listener, but doesn't take into account the new values when it changes. And so, the result of that is that the line in the JSX:

```ts
<p>value of count after rerender: {count}</p>
```

will update on each rerender, but the `console.log` of the event listener will always print `5`.

### Solution

The solution to that is simple. Add the `isScrollReached` state as a dependency for the `useEffect`. In the counter example above, it would look as follows:

```ts
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('click', onWindowClick)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('click', onWindowClick)
    }

  }, [count])
```

That way, each re-render when the state changes, the cleanup of the `useEffect` will run, removing the no-longer-relevant eventListener, and will add a new event listener, with the new state value.

---

## Edit:

The solution I gave works, but it cause the `useEffect` to re-run each render. as Martin suggested in the comments, using a ref with `useRef` would be better.